# Devise App/Views File is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have added devise to my project a few days ago and it has been working fine but for whatever reason the folder is missing from the app/views folder. I'm completely lost for ideas on where to look or what to do

Answer (score 2):

Run this in your terminal in your rails app directory: `rails generate devise:views`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Answer (score 0):

If you already had those views but they seem to have vanished. You could look into your commit history to find out when they were removed and get it back. If you are using `git` as your version control system. You may try this :

```
git log -- [file path]
```